# Efficiency mapping plugin for any java IDE

Tags: java, plugins, performance

I'm searching for some plugin that can perform this to me (even in similar way): I need a plugin that can map the code efficiency of an object line by line using colors... for example from red to blue making red the lines more "inefficient" (or, easier.. that takes more time) down gradually to blue the most efficient ones.
Is there something? If not, I think I'll build it if someone needs beyond me. Do you think you would find it interesting? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How would you measure efficiency?

Comment: @PeterLawrey simply measuring the milliseconds of execution for every line, to make it more accurate It could analyze even the various levels of abstraction of the line: for example if a line create a new object, I could estimate the execution time better mapping the used constructor of that object too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time a line of code take is usually in nano-seconds (one millionth of a milli-second) and the time it takes to measure time is about the same.  Sometimes the operation takes a fraction of the time that it takes to get the nanoTime().

Code runs faster as it is optimised dynamically and how long it takes depends on the inputs you use.  This means that a line which takes say 100 micro-seconds can take 1 micro-seconds later.

If a line of code takes 10 micro-seconds, is that efficient or inefficient?  You would have to compare it to how else it could have been implemented.

What you can to is use static code analysis for common performance mistakes.  IntelliJ has about 30 checks for common inefficiencies with auto-fixes.  I suggest you look at the code analysis in IntelliJ. The code might still be inefficient but you will at least fix things so obvious a program can fix the code for you.

Comment: I'm sorry I expressed myself badly (I'm a non-native speaker sorry),the gool of the plugin that I'm searching for is not a plugin that tells me what can be optimized and what not, but something that can map me the distribution of the time spent running a program, mapping at every abstration so I can tell if something is inefficient or not easier: making an abstraction mapping can bypass the problem of milliseconds at all for example if I got a cycle, it will map the entire cycle time, and the "body execution time" of that cycle, if it's less than a millisecond I don't need it.

Comment: @user2993157 do you mean a CPU/Memory profiler like VisualVM or Java Mission Control?  I prefer YourKit.

Comment: and then I can tell if 10 microseconds are inefficient or not creating a function of the analysis and studying its maximum-minimum

Comment: @user2993157 You can measure how much time is spent in each methods, but that won't tell you if it is inefficient or not as it might be that 10 ms is as fast as it can be made to go.

Comment: Not really like JProfiler, more integrated, I don't want graphs, numbers or comments. Colors are some kind of sense, and need not to be interpreted, and then I'm not sure that profilers show me abstractions

Comment: I know, it can't tell me for sure, but comparing the different abstraction it can map and flag a probable "too slow area"

Comment: @user2993157 If I have a method which an application takes 10 ms, is that inefficient or efficient?  If you have an inefficient method which is never called, do you care?  If you have an efficient method which is used a lot and worth check it could be more efficient, wouldn't you want to know that?

Comment: @user2993157 Can you clarify how it could do that?

Comment: I'll answer you in a few comments: "If I have a method which an application takes 10 ms, is that inefficient or efficient?" it depends on the average time spent for every line and it's variance. Using those two you're able to tell if a piece of code takes too much or not compared to the rest.

Comment: "If you have an inefficient method which is never called, do you care?" of course I care, with a mapping for every abstraction I can take care of it, what it needs is just a few input samples.

Comment: "If you have an efficient method which is used a lot and worth check it could be more efficient, wouldn't you want to know that?" Yes of course, mapping that method with its input samples.

Comment: @user2993157 This is interesting, so if it take 10 ms most of the time and sometimes a GC occurs or your thread sleeps, or blocks or is context switched, then it would be inefficient?  That would describe all code.

Comment: How much time is it worth spending optimising code which wouldn't make any difference to the application?

Comment: @user2993157 BTW I describe code which triggers a GC, or context switches, or blocks as inefficient, but very few Java developers code that way. Like <100 in the world.

Comment: @user2993157 what is it doesn't need to sleep, that would be inefficient. IMHO most uses of Thread.sleep and Thread.yield are not needed and are inefficient, which is why static analysis tools flag these as an issue.

Comment: The thing is that everything can be done, what it needs is just foresee everything. I'm not here for projecting the design of the plugin, just wanted to know if it exists yet and if someone beyond me is interested about that.

Comment: @user2993157 I am very interested, but I doubt such a solution exists as it is very hard problem to solve.

Comment: @user2993157 Just writing a program which determines if your GC is running efficiently is hard enough. Working out if a method could be written more efficiently is something most human developers struggle with.

Comment: Even if it is not possible to know exactly what gc does, it's still possible to estimate its work doing tests and making some statistics.

Comment: @user2993157 yes, but try to find a tool which does this for G1 ;)

Comment: I'm sorry, don't know what you're talking about, I've heard about it but never studied something about that.

Comment: @user2993157 G1 is the latest collector in HotSpot. I has been around for a few years but none of the tools which monitor GC logs can produce good reports for it.  You would think it was simple but in reality it is much, much harder.